# Android Studio update problem - Failed connection

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, updates

I'm trying to update Android Studio to 3.3.1 version, after waiting for update to download I get this error message
[image]

[image]

What is the problem with this update ? 'Open downlaod page' leads to this: https://developer.android.com/studio/?utm_source=android-studio
and that path  D:\ANDROIDSTUDIO\bin\ANDROIDSTUDIOSystemConfig.AndroidStudio3.1system\tmp\patch-update leads to a folder with path.jar file? I'm really confused with this update,

Answer (score 0):

**I know 3 solutions that answer**

- You can download and install the latest version of Android Studio
  from this [Download](https://developer.android.com/studio/).
- [Configuring an HTTP or HTTPS proxy On
  gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#sec%3aaccessing_the_web_via_a_proxy)
- [Set up the Android Studio
  proxy](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config#setup-proxy)